# SQL Distinct Duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct

I am sure this is a simple question and I swear I searched the forum but no help.  I have a SQL Query that I want distinct SYS.Name0:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SYS.Name0 As 'PC Name', PR.Name0 AS 'Printer Name'
FROM v_R_System SYS
INNER JOIN v_GS_PRINTER_DEVICE PR
ON SYS.ResourceID = PR.ResourceID
WHERE SYS.AD_Site_Name0 = 'Texas'
```

I am getting duplicate SYS.Name0 (PC Names) even with DISTINCT.

Searching the forum I then included a `GROUP BY SYS.Name0`

But then I get the error:

> Column 'v_GS_PRINTER_DEVICE.Name0' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you should specify what you mean by duplicates by showing the results. Try selecting other columns and check.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Distinct and group by return unique records.  Not unique columns.  if you want a list of PC names, then you can't return printer name as well; or you have to concatenate all the printer names together as well such as group_concat would do in mySQL; or return the min or max printer...

Answer (score 0):

If you want other columns, you should use `group by`.  Then you have to decide what to do about the other column, something like:

```
SELECT SYS.Name0 As PC_Name, MAX(PR.Name0) AS Printer_Name
FROM v_R_System SYS INNER JOIN
     v_GS_PRINTER_DEVICE PR
     ON SYS.ResourceID = PR.ResourceID
WHERE SYS.AD_Site_Name0 = 'Texas'
GROUP BY SYS.Name0;
```

Note:  I advise you not to use single quotes for column names.  Use the delimited defined for your database, probably double quotes, square braces, or back ticks.

Comment: That did it, putting the MAX in front of PR.Name0, and thanks for the single quote heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Include columns to get group by result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SYS.Name0 AS 'PC Name', PR.Name0 AS 'Printer Name'
FROM            v_R_System AS SYS INNER JOIN
                         v_GS_PRINTER_DEVICE AS PR ON SYS.ResourceID = PR.ResourceID
WHERE        (SYS.AD_Site_Name0 = 'Texas')
GROUP BY SYS.Name0, PR.Name0
```